# Transaction still pending after 12 hours

Tags: transactions, wallet, bitcoinj

About 12 hours ago I sent BTC 0.06304568 to my test wallet... and the transactions is still pending:

```
{
  "receiveAddress": "1KU9VwJ992UisoAYiPbRdSXDRVUCq4wdW1",
  "balance": 0,
  "net": "prod",
  "version": 0,
  "encrypted": true,
  "raw": "Wallet containing 0.06304568 BTC (spendable: 0 BTC) in:
    1 pending transactions
    0 unspent transactions
    32 spent transactions
    0 dead transactions
    Last seen best block: 377306 (Sat Oct 03 13:59:53 EDT 2015): 00000000000000000c07ea569a4be298ff78b6f5ab5df17775649dcd1bc8b68f
    ...
}
```

If if look at address `1KU9VwJ992UisoAYiPbRdSXDRVUCq4wdW1` in btc.blockr.io I get the following result:

```
Hash:           1KU9VwJ992UisoAYiPbRdSXDRVUCq4wdW1
Balance:        0.00000000 BTC
Total received: 0.00000000 BTC
Transactions:   0
Unconfirmed:    0.00000000 BTC
```

I'm a bit confused... it looks like I got a ghost transaction. Am I missing something? I don't know if it is relevant... but I use `bitcoinj` to receive bitcoins.

Comment: Got a copy of the transaction bitcoinj thinks is pending? It might not have been broadcast enough, or it might be contradicted by another transaction in the chain that bitcoinj doesn't know about.